# Adding css & js files to wordpress theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

In order to add Css & Js files to my website pages, I wanna add the following code to the **functions.php** file:

```
function cssjsloading(){

    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-rtl', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap-rtl.css', false);
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css', false);
    wp_enqueue_style('header', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/header.css', false);
    wp_enqueue_style('footer', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/footer.css', false);

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','cssjsloading');
```

instead of the following code in my `<head></head>` tag file, but it is not working!

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/bootstrap-rtl.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/header.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/header.css" />
```

I would be most grateful if you could help me

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove your `false` from `wp_enqueue_style` parameters if you do not need versioning.

Try simple `wp_enqueue_style('style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css'');` and check if this is working.